# echo php variable in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php

How to echo a php variable into a script of highchart js? Im using the column chart

```
<?php $value=75 ?>
```

at the `series` section

```
series: [{
            name: 'TRAF',
            data: [<?php echo $value?>, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }]
```

any solution will really helps.

Comment: if the $value are in the same file it works

Comment: you have no ';' after $value

Comment: it just a semi colon issue?????

Answer (score 0):

Mixing php with js is a bad habit, you can either store the $value in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$value?>" id="txtChart" name="txtChart" />
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var txtChart = $("#txtChart").val();
series: [{
        name: 'TRAF',
        data: [txtChart, 71.5, 106.4....]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need to place **;** at the end of your code line, like below:

```
<?php $value=75; ?>
```

However you should avoid using php with js. Something like this mmr's answer would be better to maintain